# Excel 2013 date format conversion. 30 Jan, 15 18:02:05 to 30.01.2015

Tags: excel, date, text, numeric

In MS Excel 2013 I import a CSV file, no matter if I format it using the delimined or any other option the results are the same. My date in Excel looks like: 30 Jan, 15 18:02:05 in a single cell. All I need is to convert it to a date format 30.01.2015 for example. I have a column of these and need to convert the values at once. (I tried TEXT, DATE, MID, DATEVALUE, MONTH, DATEVALUE...) but none of them are able to convert the date format. Also it does not matter if I convert it with format cells...to date it always displays the same i.e. 30 Jan, 15 18:02:05

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Getting a bit frustrating, thanks for any advice. Most of the above give a #VALUE error.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1** in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1) & "-" & MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,3) & "-20" & MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,2))
```

and format **B1** as *dd.mm.yyyy* for example:

[image]