# Excel Convert date type: 22nd july 2015 into 22/07/2015

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hi as the title says is there a piece of VBA or a formula that converts dates like
22nd January 2015 into 22/01/2015?

Did not agree with people down voting, or the other question "answering" this as it did not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel 2013 date format conversion. 30 Jan, 15 18:02:05 to 30.01.2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345674/excel-2013-date-format-conversion-30-jan-15-180205-to-30-01-2015)

Comment: Look at the [`DATEVALUE` function](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/DATEVALUE-function-4969e941-2edc-4292-89df-a82f02d14972?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA) and cell formatting.

Comment: give a proper example with a screenshot of your data, or a link to your data sheet

Comment: Does your data actually look like `22nd January 2015` exactly, or is it more like `22 January 2015`, etc.?

Comment: it looks like 22nd January 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should work with any two-letter ordinal number suffixes:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,4),"nd",),"rd",),"st",),"th",)
 &
 MID(A1,5,99),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

**Example**

[image]

(If not for August, this formula could be simplified a bit.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim d As Date

d = CDate("22 July 2015")
Range("A1") = d
Range("B1") = Format(d, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```